Monoid structure on field of rational functions / algebra that is equal to field + monoid
Let $\mathbb F$ be a field.  Recall that the field of rational functions $\mathbb F(X)$ can be presented as fractions $\frac{P}{Q}$ where $P,Q\in\mathbb F[X]$ are polynomials (we silently assume equality up to common divisors of $P$ and $Q$, so that e.g. $\frac{X^2-1}{X+1}=\frac{X-1}{1}$, as usual).
The field of fractions is a field, with addition and multiplication given by the usual operations on fractions, e.g. $\frac{P}{Q}+\frac{P'}{Q'}=\frac{P*Q'+Q*P'}{Q*Q'}$.
Notation: suppose $P\in\mathbb F[X]$ is a polynomial and suppose $\frac{P'}{Q'}\in\mathbb F(X)$ is a fraction.  Write
$$
P(\frac{P'}{Q'})\in\mathbb F(X)
$$
to denote the fraction obtained by replacing $X$ by $\frac{P'}{Q'}$ in $P$.  E.g. if $P=X^2+1$ and $P'=X+1$ and $Q'=X$ then $P(\frac{P'}{Q'})=(\frac{X+1}{X})^2+1=\frac{X^4+3X^2+1}{X^2}$.
So far, so standard.  Now note that the field of fractions has a monoid structure (a set with an associative composition $\circ$ and an identity $id$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) given by
$$
\frac{P}{Q} \circ \frac{P'}{Q'} = \frac{P(\frac{P'}{Q'})}{Q(\frac{P'}{Q'})} . 
$$
The identity element $id$ of this monoid is $\frac{X}{1}$.
The construction above suggests a general notion of a "monoidal field".  This is a structure that is a field under $(0,1,+,*,/)$, and is also a monoid under $(id,\circ)$, subject to some simple axioms binding these together (inspired by the example of the field of fractions above): so e.g. we would expect an axiom $(a+b)\circ c = (a\circ c)+(b\circ c)$.
My questions are:

Has the monoid structure on the field of rational functions between explicitly studied, and if so, can anyone provide references?
Have "monoidal fields" been studied before (presumably under a different name), or something like them, and if so, can anyone provide references?

Thank you.

Unfortunately this is not a monoid structure because composition is not always defined: for instance you cannot define $\frac{1}{X-2}\circ 2$. Basically you can't define $Q\circ R$ if $R$ is a constant which is a pole of $Q$. That can be resolved by taking regular functions $\mathbb{P}^1\to \mathbb{P}^1$, which can obviously be composed.

Thank you very much @CaptainLama, you are right.
Pease could you define "regular functions ℙ1→ℙ1"? I ask because I don't use the notation ℙ1 in my question, so what is this? And by "regular" do you mean total functions that are always nonzero, or something else? Thank you.

@CaptainLama By using regular functions on the projective line, you resolve the problem with composition, but now you have a constant $\infty$ (as in your example of $\frac1{X-2}\circ2$) and you lose the field structure because of things like $\infty-\infty$.
